Vuetify Data Table Transpose
I currently have a standard table which has time moving down on the y-axis. This table has many rows because there are many data points, but few columns.

I want to transpose this so that time moves on the x-axis and the columns become rows, but I'm not sure how to do this with the Vuetify Data Table, if it's possible at all. Here is an example of the type of table I am looking for (in Excel):

Here is my Vuetify data table:
<template>
  <v-data-table-virtual
    height="700"
    :items="formattedData"
  ></v-data-table-virtual>
</template>

formattedData is an array of objects where the keys specify the header names and the values specify the values.

You might be able to solve it using Computed Property.
<template>
  <v-data-table-virtual
    :items="formattedData"
  ></v-data-table-virtual>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        values: [
          {
            time: 1709949617000, //sample
          },
          ...
        ],
      }
    },
    computed: {
      formattedData() {
        return this.values.map((item,i) => {
          item.time = this.getTime(item.time); //methods
          return item;
        })
      },
    },
    //calculate unix time
    methods:{
       getTime:(time)=>{
           time = new Date(time * 1000 );
           return time.toLocaleTimeString([], {timeStyle: 'short'});
       }
    }
  }
</script>

References and examine(can confirm it as type of HH:ii)
Data table - Virtual tables
Thank you.
